# QField Compatible Devices / Requirements

Tags: qfield, compatibility, tablet, system-requirements

I recently purchase a Samsung Tab A 10.1 (2019) and can't open QField projects on it. After attempting to open my project file it gets stuck. I read a [comment from opengis.ch](https://www.opengis.ch/2013/11/07/qgis-for-android-does-not-run-on-galaxy-tab-3-nor-on-all-intel-based-tablets/) from 2013 that "currently QGIS for android runs on ARM v7 tablets only. I currently have no time to make an x86 build". Is that still the case for the 2020 version? What are the device requirements to properly run QField? Or am I confusing my error with another common bug/error?

Comment: Please provide more details in your question - such as whether you have been able to open *any* projects, such as a simple single layer project, how many and what sort of layers are in the project, are they using relative paths, do you have any non-filesystem (i.e. wms or tile) layers, etc...?

Comment: The post is updated with current information. What you experience is likely related to the project configuration and not to the hardware you are using.